# rearranging JSON output using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have my python code that retrieves data from a SQL select statement and outputs as a JSON format.

```
try:        
    cur.execute("My SQL Statement is here")
    con.commit()
    for results in cur.fetchall():
        temp = recordsConv(results)
        records_list.append(temp)

    invoice_records = {'invoiceDetails':records_list}
    y = json.dumps(invoice_records)
    payload = json.loads(y)
    return(payload)
        
    else:
        return(strg)

except error as e:
    raise error({"Error": True,"message":str(e)})

def recordsConv(y):
    try:
        record = {}
        record["File Number"] = y[0]
        record["House Bill Number"] = y[1]
        record["Handling Station"] = y[2]
        record["Charge Code Desc"] = y[3]
        record["Total"] = y[4]
```

The execution is working fine and this is the sample output

```
{
    "invoiceDetails": [
        {
            "File Number": "11111",
            "House Bill Number": "22222",
            "Handling Station": "ABC",
            "Charge Code Desc": "DUTY AND TAX",
            "Total": 251.1
        },
        {
            "File Number": "11111",
            "House Bill Number": "22222",
            "Handling Station": "ABC",
            "Charge Code Desc": "CARTAGE",
            "Total": 120.0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the output, My data is getting duplicated. I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
{
    "invoiceDetails": [
        {
            "File Number": "11111",
            "House Bill Number": "22222",
            "Handling Station": "ABC",             
            "Charge Code Desc" : [
                {
                    "DUTY AND TAX" : 251.1,
                    "CARTAGE" : 120.0
                    }
     ]  
   }
   ]
}
```

My try: I kept the appending part out of the for loop like this

```
for results in cur.fetchall():
        temp = recordsConv(results)
records_list.append(temp)
```

rest of the code is same, but my output is not as expected

output:

```
{
    "invoiceDetails": [
        {
            "File Number": "11111",
            "House Bill Number": "22222",
            "Handling Station": "ABC",
            "Charge Code Desc": "CARTAGE",
            "Total": 120.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using Pandas for such data manipulations. It will save you a lot of time in the long run. In this case you would simply use the groupby operation.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS, you may be to adjust the SQL to return json.